# Many to Many | View Error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship. My main object is a members table and these members can have multiple interests as a dropdown selection. A interest can also have multiple members.

When I test my create view I get the following error:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'tomcrud.interest_member' doesn't exist (SQL: select `interests`.*, `interest_member`.`member_id` as `pivot_member_id`, `interest_member`.`interest_id` as `pivot_interest_id` from `interests` inner join `interest_member` on `interests`.`id` = `interest_member`.`interest_id` where `interest_member`.`member_id` is null) (View: G:\laragon\www\tomcrud\resources\views\members\partials\member_form.blade.php) (View: G:\laragon\www\tomcrud\resources\views\members\partials\member_form.blade.php)

If I read laravel docs correctly, the interest_member table should be created automatically with all the relevant keys. I can't see such a table in my schema. I can however see my members and interests tables.

I believe my Models are configured correctly:

Member Model:

```
class Member extends Model
{
    public function interests()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Interest', 'interest_member');
    }
}
```

Interest Model:

```
class Interest extends Model
{
    public function members()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Member');
    }
}
```

My MemberController create() function:

```
public function create()
    {
        $member = new Member;
        $data = array();
        $data['member'] = $member;
        $data['languages'] = Language::pluck('name', 'id');
        $data['interests'] = Interest::pluck('name', 'id');

        return view('members.create', $data);
    }
```

The multi select dropdown portion of my member_form blade:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('interest_id[]', 'Interest:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('interest_id[]', $interests, $member->interests->pluck('id'), ['multiple' => true, 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: The tables aren't generated automatically; you need to add a migration for `interest_member` and populate it with the correct columns, then update your schema. Where did you read in the Docs that the tables were auto-generated? (Asking out of curiosity)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `interest_member` table which can have 3 columns(id, member_id, interest_id). Then you can create this type of relation between them.

Comment: But the docs says something else? I ran: php artisan make:model Interest --migration to create the Interest Model and interests table in the db. According to the docs it is my understanding that Laravel will automatically create a interest_member table with the foreign keys setup automatically. Am I misreading that in the Eloquent >> Relationships >> Many to Many part of the Laravel 5.6 docs?

The docs does not give any examples of setting up this 3rd table nor how to configure the foreign key, hence my assumption that all of this is setup automatically.

Comment: check this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many, they also have mentioned about 3rd table(role_user).

Comment: I went through that a couple of times, but was not very helpful. I'll create the interest_member table and then I'll need to figure out how to link the foreign keys